# Karma test won't create new instance of component

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, karma-jasmine

I have written a simple test for my Angular component that checks my component toBeTruthy().  When I run it I get the error: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined at new SomeComponent...'

```
import { AssemblyComponent } from './assembly.component';

describe('SomeComponent', () => {
    let component: AssemblyComponent;

    let mockDynamicTemplateBuilder;
    let mockActivatedRoute;
    let mockINavigationService;
    let mockISiteConfigRetrievalService;

    beforeEach( () => {
        component = new AssemblyComponent (mockDynamicTemplateBuilder, mockActivatedRoute, mockINavigationService, mockISiteConfigRetrievalService);
    });

    describe('create the component', () => {

        it('component should be truthy', () => {

            expect(component).toBeTruthy();
        });
    });
});
```

The component itself looks as follows:

```
export class AssemblyComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {

    // reference for a <div> with #dynamicContentPlaceHolder
    @ViewChild('dynamicContentPlaceHolder', { read: ViewContainerRef })
    protected dynamicComponentTarget: ViewContainerRef;
    // this will be reference to dynamic content - to be able to destroy it
    protected componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;

    private sub: any;
    // until ngAfterViewInit, we cannot start (firstly) to process dynamic stuff
    protected wasViewInitialized = false;

    // wee need Dynamic component builder
    constructor(
        protected templateBuilder: DynamicTemplateBuilder,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private navigationService: INavigationService,
        private siteConfigRetrivalService: ISiteConfigRetrievalService
    ) {
        // when there is change, the subscription is invoked
        // based on the current route params
        console.log('break line');
        this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
           // fetching page id
            let pageIdLocal = this.navigationService.getPageId();
            let childpage: string = params['childid'];
            if (childpage !== undefined) {
                pageIdLocal = childpage;
            }
            let grandchildpage: string = params['grandchildid'];
            if (grandchildpage !== undefined) {
                pageIdLocal = grandchildpage;
            }
            console.log(' Fetching Page for ' + pageIdLocal);
            // type of device
            let deviceType = this.navigationService.getDeviceType();
            // returns meta data for that page, data coming from that JSON file
            this.siteConfigRetrivalService.getPageConfiguration(pageIdLocal, deviceType).subscribe((data: any) => {
                this.renderDynamicContent(data, deviceType);
            });

        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(' In Assembly OnInit ');
    }
...
```

It seems that I cannot test for initialization of my component (or any of the methods) is because the logic in the body of the constructor needs to be mocked before the component initializes.  My understanding is that you are really not supposed to have logic in the body of your constructor.  Is code like this even testable...? I also noticed private variables here, which I guess would prevent one from testing them directly.  How would I approach this?

Comment: That error may be happening somewhere else not within your code sample because I don't see `params` defined or referenced anywhere in that snipped.

Comment: You are right, I just looked at the component.  There is some logic with in the body of the constructor that does something with params.  Is that convention?  In such a case you would have to mock all of the logic in the body of the constructor before you can test any method...that does not seem right.

Comment: I can't speak to convention within Angular, but if you want to use that component then conceptually you will have to stub or mock anything it depends on.

Comment: Well regardless of Angular that makes tests much more difficult to write in addition to making them brittle...Just an observation.

Comment: If the component uses params of the `ActivatedRoute` for example, then you have to provide them in your testing environment. you can also mock them. you should update your question with your `SomeComponent` code, at least the declaration of properties and constructor.

Comment: oh and you should use `TestBed` to test components instead of trying to create the Components manually for testing.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the code to include the component itself.  Hope this makes my questions clearer!